# Android studio) logcat doesn't print out any custom message

Tags: android, android-studio, logging, logcat

I tried a lot of logs(Log.v(), Log.d(), Log.i(), Log.w(), Log.wtf(), Log.e()) to print out some text in my android studio
Unfortunately, nothing of them works.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WordsList list = new WordsList();
    Log.i(TAG, "new word" + list.getRandomWord());
}
```

this is the code.

But as you see here,
[image]

the logcat is empty.

[image]
debug is still empty when I use Log.d

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you see in the images, no logs work. new words are just not printed out.

What I have tried:

- Disable developer options and restart my smartphone
- Restarting android studio
- Invalidate Cashes/Restart
- Show only selected application
- Edit filter configuration and set log message to "new word"

Nothing of them worked.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried "No filters"?

Comment: @Zain Yes. Doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that USB debugging is enabled on the device under the Developer options

Comment: @Zain Yes. I checked that hundreds of times ...

Comment: in `TAG` variable just set it to a special word without any spaces or special characters, for instance `LOG_TAG`, and filter with that instead of `new word`. Also make sure that you are at `verbose` or at the level you are logging at

Comment: @Zain Thank you. I rebuilt the project, set log level, stopped the program and started again with android studio. Works now!